# Override initial value of a member variable of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am very confused with the inheritance right now. I planned to simply override the initial value of a variable. In the following code i just inherit the base class and try to get it's name, which is saved as a string withing the class. I expected that the derived class can override this value, however it does not do it.

My expected out put was

```
Derived
Derived
```

However i get

```
Base
Base
```

What is the correct way to implement the following?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void id(){
        std::cout << id_ << std::endl;
    }
    std::string id_ = "Base";
};   



struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual ~Derived() = default;
    std::string id_ = "Derived";
};   


int main(){
    Base* b = new Derived();
    Derived* d = new Derived();
    b->id();
    d->id();
    delete d;
    delete b;                                                                                                          
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Member variables cannot be virtual (i.e. overridable), just methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the correct way to implement the following?

Without meaning to sound difficult, it really depends on exactly what you want to achieve.

I'm going to make a guess that we're simply be asking an object what type it is, regardless of which interface we're calling on:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  virtual const std::string id() const {
    return "Base";
  }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  virtual const std::string id() const override {
    return "Derived";
  }
};
```

Here's another way:

```
struct Base {
  virtual Base(std::string ident = "Base") 
  : _id(std::move(ident))
  {}

  virtual ~Base() = default;

  std::string& id() const {
    return _id;
  }

private:
  std::string _id;

};

struct Derived : Base {
  Derived() : Base("Derived") {}
};
```

And another, using value is interface, but note that this will disable the assignment operator

```
struct Base {
  virtual Base(std::string ident = "Base") 
  : id(std::move(ident))
  {}

  virtual ~Base() = default;

  const std::string id;

};

struct Derived : Base {
  Derived() : Base("Derived") {}
};
```

This list is by no means exhaustive.

Comment: but it's a very good start :) It gives the OP several ways to achieve this, and I'm sure experimentation will show which one is best for them.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual functions exist, not virtual member variables.

What you do in your `Derived` class is *define* a new member variable `id_` that hides it's parent.  The `id()` function, however, is referring to the `id_` defined *in that context*.

If you want to override the behavior, you should override the `id()` function:

```
class Derived: public Base {
    std::string id() const override { return "Derived"; }
};
```

Comment: isn't there any other more general way?

Comment: I have suggested one. Whether this or that are better depends on your situation, so weigh them up.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply give `Base` a constructor that sets `id` and have `Derived` call this constructor with its 'overridden' value? Boom: 'virtual data' according to the derived type.

Having said that, a virtual method might be more akin to encapsulation and provide opportunity for more elaborate behaviour later.

(*Edit: I posted this as a comment and then converted it, by which point Richard had just beaten me to posting the answer. No copying has taken place!*)

Answer (score 0):

Since function id() is virtual, in both case object pointer is Derived type only.

```
Base* b = new Derived(); // object type is Derived
b->id();
```

here b is pointer of type Derived 
but the "Derived" class has no implementation for id(), since there is no entry for id() in virtual lookup table for derived class object so it will call base class function id()

similarly other case also

```
Derived* d = new Derived(); //object type is Derived
d->id();
```

since id() method is not defined in the derived class it will call the base class id() only.

one more doubt is how you initialized the variable "id_" inside the class?

Comment: Nope, that pointer is very much a `Base` type, not `Derived`, though it may arrive at either at runtime via the vtable. And what is your doubt (question?) about initialising `id_`? That is brace-or-equal initialisation where a member variable can be given a default value without appearing in a constructor initialisation list.

Comment: Do you mean std::string id_ = "Base";  is correct  inside the class??                                               Is it possible to initialize a data member(which is not static) inside the class?? I tried in VS 2012 but it is throwing an error "data member initialization is not allowed"

Comment: VS fairly often lags behind some new features of C++ standards, and that one only came out shortly after C++11, in which this feature was added. Yes, it's allowed. Just search for it. (btw, this makes the type non-POD)